# Laravel 8 template layout slots vs Laravel old sections, yields and extends?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I'm starting a new project with Laravel 8 and I realised that there is two ways to extends a layout from a view, the first is with the "new" way, using:

- ### New Parent Layout Design

```php
{{-- any other *.blade.php file that wants to inherit base-view.blade.php view --}}
<x-base-view>
   {{-- $slot is this everything block --}}
</x-base-view>
```

While the `base-view` is the `base-view.blade.php` blade file that has something like:

```html
{{-- views/base-view.blade.php --}}

<html>
   <body>
      <div class="content">
         {{ $slot }}
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And we have this other way:

- ### "Old" Parent Layout Design

The old way consists in using `@extends()`, `@yield()`, `@section()`, to extends, render a section and define a section respectively

## My Question

my question is: which is the best option? I mean, what is the advantages of using the first and what is the advantages of using the second?
And more importantly, what is the pitfalls of using the first or the second way?

Comment: This isn't a good question for Stackoverflow. It's a fine question, but Stackoverflow is a technical question and answer site, and yours is mostly an opinionated question on what people think is a "better" approach.

Comment: @TimLewis oh.. sorry. I don't think that this is an opinion question, but yeah, this is more close to "patterns" than "technical" I guess.

Comment: @TimLewis also, I searched about the topic but I found no one answers

Comment: Unless people can provide a technical explanation on why one method is better than the other (speed, memory usage, etc), this is an opinionated question  Since both approaches are valid and should produce the same outcome from a visible perspective (i.e. seeing the results), it's just not a great fit for SO. Like I said though, still a good question, just unlikely to get a concrete answer here. Maybe see if you can find a discussion section for Laravel/Blade templating? I'm not sure where that would be, but it's unfortunately not here. Best of luck though!

Comment: @TimLewis, well... I think that I know the answer. First: I don't know if this new way will override the "old" way on the newest laravel's versions, if it will, so I will need to change my entire application views. Second: I really think that the "old" way is more concise and avoid cumbersome (in maintaining) of what is a "component" and what is a "laravel slots view feature" (because the new way uses the same component calling pattern `<x-...></x-...>`). So I think that the "old" way is better, but it's not a concise answer, you know, it's just a guess, and it can give me a lot of work..

Comment: @TimLewis this is a pitfall when asking questions that I have yet to fully understand. The person asking the question assumes there is a " technical explanation on why one method is better than the other (speed, memory usage, etc)". They search online and can't find a definitive answer, so they post the question here. here the question is dismissed claiming opinionated with no data supporting that the two methods are the same besides providing the same visuals. How could the person asking the question know for fact that their question is opinionated before asking the question?

Comment: @essentialz You're not wrong, but as I've stated in my other comments, there is nothing wrong with the question being asked, except that Stackoverflow is not the correct place to ask this question. For your question, "how could they know it's opinionated before asking", that's easy; any question that is worded like "Is A better than B?", or "A and B; which is the best?", etc. are likely going to be opinion-based (there are exceptions). Since "better" and "best" are subjective terms, what I find better is going to be different than what someone else thinks is better, hence opinionated.